# Android Action Bar not showing on displayOptions - useLogo

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme, android-styles, graphical-logo

I have an `actionBarStyle` that I have implemented in my app for my `ActionBar`. Here is the xml code below:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyCustomActionBar</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MyCustomActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:displayOptions">useLogo</item>
    </style>
```

And here is my `Activity OnCreate`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_logo);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    initializeViews();
    manageFragments();
}
```

The Problem is that my `ActionBar` doesn't show at all and when I remove the `displayOptions` item from My XML. It shows with the title. Now I can always remove the title (set the title string to just blank) but I don't want that as it shows the default `ActionBar` style/theme for a few seconds and then my custom theme (I guess you know this one). I don't know what the problem is. Please help. Thanks...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you set the `android:logo` in the theme you shouldn't need to set it in code.

I think you may also need `showHome` in your display options e.g.

```
<item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>
```

**EDIT**

Below is an example theme I use to hide the logo and display the title in the action bar, this sample is using `ActionBarSherlock` so you will need to adjust the parent style names accordingly if you aren't using it.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
   <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background_primary</item>
   <item name="android:icon">@drawable/appicon</item>    
   <!-- For the home as up icon on sub pages -->
   <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/back</item>
   <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/back</item>          
   <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
   <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
<item name="android:displayOptions">showTitle</item>
<item name="displayOptions">showTitle</item>

<item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
<item name="titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>    
<item name="android:background">@color/actionbar_bg_color</item>
<item name="background">@color/actionbar_bg_color</item>
<item name="android:backgroundStacked">@color/actionbar_bg_color</item>
<item name="backgroundStacked">@color/actionbar_bg_color</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works from 4.2 api version.

In your ActionBar style add this…

```
<item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>
<item name="displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>

<!-- Support library compatibility -->
<item name="android:logo">@drawable/ic_home</item>
<item name="logo">@drawable/ic_home</item>
```

Complete Example , adding a new Theme for your complete App.

```
<!-- This is the generated app theme -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- general styles for the action bar -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">

    <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>

    <item name="android:logo">@drawable/ic_home</item>
     <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="logo">@drawable/ic_home</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want use code to implement this effect, you can call below code from a Fragment.

```
ActionBarActivity activity = (ActionBarActivity) getActivity();
activity.getActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
activity.getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

and you need to specify the logo attribute of the activity in the AndroidManifest.xml, for example,

```
    <activity
        android:name=".....MainEntryActivity"
        android:label="@string/label_main"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:logo="@drawable/ic_ios_logo"
        android:theme="@style/AppCompatTheme" >
    </activity>
```