# Change ActionBar Label to Image [API10]

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Is there a way how to change ActionBar label (text) to image?

I already vanished the text, but i am not able to get image there.
styles.xml looks like in google tutorials:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme"
        parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
        parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/full_logo</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
        <item name="background">@drawable/full_logo</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar title text -->
    <style name="MyActionBarTitleText"
        parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <!-- The textColor property is backward compatible with the Support Library -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

But the drawable/full_logo image is stretched according to bar dimensions. so it is deformed on orientation change.

Is there a way how to replace text label with image in API 10?
If not, in which lowest API is it possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ianhanniballake's answer helped me to find the solution:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme"
        parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
        parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>
        <item name="logo">@drawable/full_logo</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

The image is automatically centered (or shrinked) to be visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set a custom view to your actionbar. So simply put your imageview there:

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

final View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.action_bar_header, null);
final ImageView logoImage = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.action_bar_header_image);

actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setCustomView(header);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a logo to display a branding image rather than the label:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="displayOptions">useLogo</item>
    <item name="logo">@drawable/full_logo</item>
</style>
```

Note that as of [AppCompat v21](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html), you do not need the `android:` namespaced attributes. If you are using an older version you will need to duplicate each attribute to use both the `android:` prefixed and non-prefixed form.

Comment: Your solution did not work as is, but leaded me to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20428261/android-action-bar-not-showing-on-displayoptions-uselogo and it helped me. thanks.